# What's the best way to access columns of an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

In Matlab, one can access a column of an array with `:`:

```
>> array=[1 2 3; 4 5 6]

array =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6


>> array(:,2)

ans =

     2
     5
```

How to do this in Python?

```
>>> array=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> array[:,2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
>>> array[:][2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

### Addendum

I'd like an example applied to an array of dimensions greater than three:

```
>> B = cat(3, eye(3), ones(3), magic(3))

B(:,:,1) =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1


B(:,:,2) =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1


B(:,:,3) =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> B(:,:,1)                             

ans =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1

>> B(:,2,:)

ans(:,:,1) =

     0
     1
     0


ans(:,:,2) =

     1
     1
     1


ans(:,:,3) =

     1
     5
     9
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [Numpy](https://numpy.org/).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> a[:, 2]
array([3, 6])
```

If you come from Matlab, this should be of interest: [Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)

Comment: As @unutbu said, to achieve the same effect as `array(:,2)` in Matlab, use `a[:, 1]`, since it's 0-based in Python.

Comment: Not sure if the question was general or with a view to use some numerical code. If it's the latter, you should definitely look into Numpy/Scipy (perhaps the SciKits too depending on what you do). I wouldn't try to do numerical code in Python without a library dedicated for this purpose.

Comment: How to do this for an array of dimension greater than 3?

Answer (score 8):

You can group data in a two-dimensional list by column using the built-in [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
>>> array=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> zip(*array)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> zip(*array)[1]
(2, 5)
```

Note that the index starts at 0, so to get the second column as in your example you use `zip(*array)[1]` instead of `zip(*array)[2]`.  `zip()` returns tuples instead of lists, depending on how you are using it this may not be a problem, but if you need lists you can always do `map(list, zip(*array))` or `list(zip(*array)[1])` to do the conversion.

Comment: So this is just [matrix transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). Is there any special comment for converting it to tuple?

Answer (score 4):

If you use Matlab, you probably will want to install [NumPy](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=numpy&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://numpy.scipy.org/&ei=fMsVT9q-PIbr0gGC5fVR&usg=AFQjCNHc8BZqObo1c9wGn_Z50mJmNAkHiQ):
Using NumPy, you can do this:

```
In [172]: import numpy as np

In [173]: arr = np.matrix('1 2 3; 4 5 6')

In [174]: arr
Out[174]: 
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]])

In [175]: arr[:,2]
Out[175]: 
matrix([[3],
        [6]])
```

Since Python uses 0-based indexing (while Matlab uses 1-based indexing), to get the same slice you posted you would do:

```
In [176]: arr[:,1]
Out[176]: 
matrix([[2],
        [5]])
```

---

It is easy to build numpy arrays of higher dimension as well. You could use `np.dstack` for instance:

```
In [199]: B = np.dstack( (np.eye(3), np.ones((3,3)), np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)) )

In [200]: B.shape
Out[200]: (3, 3, 3)

In [201]: B[:,:,0]
Out[201]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])

In [202]: B[:,:,1]
Out[202]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [203]: B[:,:,2]
Out[203]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
```

And here is the array formed from the second column from each of the 3 arrays above:

```
In [204]: B[:,1,:]
Out[204]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  7.]])
```

Numpy doesn't have a function to create magic squares, however. *sniff*

Comment: +1 Good catch on the array index. I'd use an array instead of a matrix, though. From [here](http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users): "*'array' or 'matrix'? Which should I use?* Short answer: Use arrays."

Comment: Yes, I agree with your preference. In general, use arrays. It is easy to convert one to the other though: `arr = np.asarray(arr)`.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing / slicing with Python using the colon results in things a bit differently than matlab.  If you have your array, `[:]` will copy it.  If you want all values at a specific index of nested arrays, you probably want something like this:

```
array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
col1 = [inner[0] for inner in array] # note column1 is index 0 in Python.
```

Answer (score 2):

If using nested lists, you can use a list comprehension:

```
array = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]
col2 = [ row[1] for row in array ]
```

Keep in mind that since Python doesn't natively know about matrices, `col2` is a list, and as such both "rows" and "columns" are the same type, namely lists. Use the `numpy` package for better support for matrix math.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_column(array, col):
  result = []
  for row in array:
    result.appen(row[col])
  return result
```

Use like this (remember that indexes start from 0):

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
>>> get_column(a, 1)
[2, 3]
```

Comment: You misspelled `.append`. Also, list comprehensions are a lot better than building lists one element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to build a list of values from that column:

```
def nthcolumn(n, matrix):
    return [row[n] for row in matrix]
```

Optionally use `itemgetter` if you need a (probably slight) performance boost:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def nthcolumn(n, matrix):
    nthvalue = itemgetter(n)
    return [nthvalue(row) for row in matrix]
```